# Getting error in an woocommerce based store. WP is not defined in meta boxes variations.php

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have a woocommerce based online store with around 70 products. Everything was working fine till yesterday, today I am getting these javascript errors

1. WP is not defined in meta boxes variations.php in product list page. (causing the list of products is not displaying in backend. Its there in db I checked.)
2. woocommerce_params not defined.(Causing plugin list not displaying but that is solved for now.)

No theme up-gradation, no woocommerce up-gradation not even wordpress. Nothing is happened.

Can anybody tell what might be the issue? I have WordPress 4.0.8 and woocommerce 2.3

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both your WordPress and WooCommerce are very out of date. I would start with backing up everything and then upgrading.

Comment: But website is live and is being used by many people, how can I take a chance if it crashes after upgrading.

Comment: Plenty of ways to clone your current site into a test environment. You can use a sub folder in your hosting account if you have space, or something like [serverpress](https://serverpress.com/) to do it locally, or a free cloudcoding account like [cloud9](https://c9.io/) to do it online.